# Pthreads. How to check is mutex locked already

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I need to write <strike>bicycle</strike> function that would be equals to pthread_mutex_trylock(...)
How can I do this?
*I could not find the source code of this function, and I'm afraid, even if I find them, they are too complex for copy-paste. But I'll upvote for the link anyway.*

I need to write simple function which could just take the mutex if it's not locked or return if it's not.

Comment: `int myTryLock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex) { return pthread_mutex_trylock(mutex); }`. Seriously... what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @mah, It's learning task. I can't use trylock :(

Comment: http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.19/pthread__mutex__trylock_8c_source.html has source for it. It's quite a bit of code but it's a single function that does its task in different ways depending on what kind of mutex it's dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My feeling is that you haven't provided enough information in your question. The actual pthread mutex implementation in glibc is a very complex beast (it's meant to support many use cases and policies) and is hardly suitable for training assignments.

Therefore, you may actually be required to do something different then digging into pthread mutex internals.

One possibility: it may be enough for you to use an alternative to `pthread_mutex_trylock`. Such alternative surely exists and is called [`pthread_mutex_timedlock`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_timedlock.html) (invoke it with timeout of 0).

Another possibility: you may need to come with your own mutex implementation (based on low level primitives, such as `futex` on Linux). This is not too complicated either: http://locklessinc.com/articles/mutex_cv_futex/.

Comment: Timedlock looks as a solution. Not sure that it is like my teacher, but I will likely use this way.

Comment: Finally, I used pthread_mutex_destroy - reinit mutex if success or just return if not :)

Comment: I will site a manual page on this: "Attempting to destroy a locked mutex results in undefined behavior". Also, what will happen if another thread tries to snatch a mutex between "destroy" and "init"? Another good one: what if mutex is unlocked but referenced by pthread_cond_wait()?